# Kotlin and Spark - SAM issues

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

Maybe I'm doing something that is not quite supported, but I really want to use Kotlin as I learn Apache Spark [with this book](http://amzn.com/1449358624)

Here is the Scala code sample I'm trying to run. The `flatMap()` accepts a [FlatMapFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/FlatMapFunction.html) SAM type:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)
val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
```

Here is my attempt to do this in Kotlin. But it is having a compilation issue on the fourth line:

```
val conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Line Counter")
val sc = SparkContext(conf)
val input = sc.textFile("C:\\spark_workspace\\myfile.txt",1)
val words = input.flatMap{ s:String -> s.split(" ") } //ERROR
```

When I hover over it I get this compile error:

[image]

Am I doing anything unreasonable or unsupported? I don't see any suggestions to autocomplete with lambdas either :(

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact the problem is solved I would like to provide some information regarding the reasons of compilation problem. In this example `input` has a type of `RDD`, whose [`flatMap()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L373) method accepts a lambda that should return `TraversableOnce[U]`. As Scala has it's own collections framework, Java collection types cannot be converted to `TraversableOnce`.

Moreover, I'm not so sure Scala `Function`s are really SAMs. As far as I can see from the screenshots Kotlin doesn't offer replacing a `Function` instance with a lambda.

Comment: Acutally, since they're using the Java API, a normal `Iterator` would do the trick:
```
val words: JavaRDD<String> = input.flatMap{ s: String -> s.split(" ").iterator() }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out. I knew there was a way since Spark supports both Java and Scala. The key to this particular problem was to use a `JavaSparkContext` instead of the Scala-based `SparkContext`.

For some reason Scala and Kotlin don't always get along with SAM conversions. But Java and Kotlin do...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Line Counter")
    val sc = JavaSparkContext(conf)
    val input = sc.textFile("C:\\spark_workspace\\myfile.txt",1)
    val words = input.flatMap { it.split(" ") }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my comment at @Michael for my fix. However, can I recommend the open source [Kotlin Spark API](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spark-api) by JetBrains for future reference? It solves many lambda errors, especially using the `Dataset` API but can also make working with Spark from Kotlin generally easier:

```
withSpark(appName = "Line Counter", master = "local") {
    val input = sc.textFile("C:\\spark_workspace\\myfile.txt", 1)
    val words = input.flatMap { s: String -> s.split(" ").iterator() }
}
```